# String Detection, ifelse(), creating a function, and dataframes -- all in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, if-statement, stringr

I have a dataframe where one of the columns is the person's academic title (Lecturer, Full Professor, Associate Professor, etc).  I was hoping to use the str_detect() function in an ifelse()  in R to (1) make them all lower case so that I could (2) assign a title.  Right now, I am just working on the variations of Associate Professor, Assistant Professor, and Postdoc (associate professor, associate Professor, Associate Professor, Associate professor).  If a match is not detected, I would like the functiion to return the original title so I can then figure out the next step.

The issue is that I am getting this error: <kbd>Error in str_detect(title, "(?i)postdoc", "PostDoc", title) :
unused argument (title)</kbd> when I try to apply nested ifelse() statements.

I am a newbie to all of this so I hope I am not violating or omitting info (especially since I am very unsure of how to add my minimal reproducible code).  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
#make the dataframe
(CPex <- data.frame(title = c('assistant professor', 'Assistant professor', 'Associate Professor', 'Chair', 'postdoc', 'lecturer', 'associate Professor')))
```

```
#this is the function to go row by row and assign the title to a new variable (title2)
changeTitle3 <- function(title) {
  tolower(title)
  title2 <- ifelse(str_detect(title, "(?i)assoc"), "Associate Professor", 
                   ifelse(str_detect(title, "(?i)assi"), "Assistant Professor",
                          ifelse(str_detect(title, "(?i)postdoc", "PostDoc", title))
                                     ))
  return(title2)
}
```

```
#testing the function
changeTitle3(CPex$title)
```

I also tried it with individual if...else statements:

```
changeTitle2 <- function(title) {
  tolower(title)
  title2 <- 
    if(str_detect(title, "(?i)assoc")) {
      return("Associate Professor")
      } else {
        if(str_detect(title, "(?i)assis")) {
          return("Assistant Professor")
          } else {
            if((str_detect(title, "(?i)post"))) {
              return("PostDoc") }
            else {
              return (title)
            }
      } } }
```

Comment: You are missing one closing bracket in your last `str_detect`. I guess it should be `ifelse(str_detect(title, "(?i)postdoc"), "PostDoc", title))`. After that, the function seems to run fine.

Comment: Also in the first line, the value should be assigned back to `title` i.e `title <- tolower(title)`

Comment: I made those corrections to get a new error:  ` Error in str_detect(title, "(?i)postdoc", "PostDoc", title) :
unused argument (title)`

Comment: @zeigna Based on your last comment, it's clear that you didn't insert the correct closing bracket suggested earlier (or your copied the wrong error message). I suggest to take a closer look at all opening and closing brackets to get the awareness of where they should be.

Comment: @benson23 I should have just copied your code.  It works!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

> You are missing one closing bracket in your last str_detect. I guess it should be ifelse(str_detect(title, "(?i)postdoc"), "PostDoc", title)). After that, the function seems to run fine. – [benson23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76015708/string-detection-ifelse-creating-a-function-and-dataframes-all-in-r#comment134067577_76015708)

This is the answer that solved OP's problem.

If *I* were writing this code, instead of using many nested if-else statements, I'd use the `case_when` function instead:

```
mutate(CPex, processed_title = case_when(
    str_detect(title, '(?i)assistant') ~ 'Assistant Professor',
    str_detect(title, '(?i)associate') ~ 'Associate Professor',
    str_detect(title, '(?i)chair') ~ 'Chair',
    str_detect(title, '(?i)postdoc') ~ 'Postdoc',
    str_detect(title, '(?i)lecturer') ~ 'Lecturer',
    TRUE ~ 'Other'))
```

Output:

```
                title     processed_title
1 assistant professor Assistant Professor
2 Assistant professor Assistant Professor
3 Associate Professor Associate Professor
4               Chair               Chair
5             postdoc             Postdoc
6            lecturer            Lecturer
7 associate Professor Associate Professor
```

You can then filter the resulting dataframe to those with the title "Other" to find those whose title value didn't match anything.